# Running Lotus Script Agent is not getting logged in Lotus Notes User log

Tags: logging, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript, agents

I have written a basic lotus script agent that shows "Hello World" in a Message Box.
When I run this agent manually, it gets executed successfully but the Event of running is not getting a log entry created in my local Log file.
The Agent is run from my local mail file. I want these logs in order to run other complex agents and to track events like automatic schedules and trigger on new mail, etc..

When I execute from some other system, the agent is getting logged. This might be a setting related issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you run an agent manually using the Action menu or from the Agent list in designer it does not log to the Notes log on the client or the server unless you specifically tell it to using the NotesLog class OpenNotesLog and related calls.

Scheduled agents, background agents and agents invoked from the web do write to the server console and the Notes Log when you issue a Message Box. Print statements in scheduled or background agents are also logged. Print Statements in agents run from the web are sent back to the browser.

I do not recommend using the agent logging to the Notes log. It quickly becomes very cluttered and hard to find your messages. Use the AgentLog or EmailLog from the NotesLog class or get the OpenNTF OpenLog tools. [OpenLog home page](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/OpenLog) Julian has done a great job with that tool.

Happy coding.

/Newbs

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to do some 'debugging', try to use "print" as this will print something in your notes client status bar.

Another tips is to use "messagebox" command, this will print text in server console (if run on server) or local log (if run locally).

Comment: Is there a code snippet or screenshot that can show how this is done?